# Keeping function reference

Tags: javascript, reference, closures

A newbie JS dilemma:

```
var a = function() {console.log(5);}

var b = a;

a = function() {console.log(6);}
```

obviously `b == function() {console.log(5);}`

The question is, how can I wrap/modify `a` by keeping the reference to the original function, so that b will point to the modified one too?

Comment: proposed a 'solution' but I have the suspicion that there's a bigger issue going on with your design. You might want to give some context so someone can probably point out how to do this JavaScript-esque. A lot of times I find myself stuck when learning a new language, it turns out I'm doing stuff in a different way than it is intended by the language; even if one gets it done, it's typically a waste of time and not helping towards improving in that language.

Comment: Nicolas is right.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.
Javascript does not support references to variables.

You could write `var b = function() { return a.apply(this, arguments); }`, but `b` will still be a different object.

Comment: "Javascript does not support references." eh?

Comment: @MGZero: Javascript does not support C++'s `var &b = a;`

Comment: Really? Try this. `var a={x:1}; var b=a; a.x=2; alert(b.x);`

Comment: @skier88: That's not a variable.

Comment: It's a variable contained in another variable. I realize it's not directly analogous to C's `&`, but it can be used to the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

a bit tongue-in-cheek, but it should achieve what you're trying to do if I get you right:

```
var b = function() { a(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var a = function() {console.log(5);}
```

...creates an object in memory -- a function -- and stores a reference to it in `a`.

Similarly, this line:

```
b = a;
```

...stores in `b` the reference that is in `a`.

So, then, you should be able to predict what this line does:

```
a = function() {console.log(6);}
```

It stores a reference to some new function in `a`. This does not affect `b` at all. In other words, `b` is *not* an *alias* for `a`. It's incidental that it once pointed at the same memory location as did `a`. They are separate, independent variables, capable of pointing at any arbitrary object in memory. They can point to the same object, sure, but that's as related as they'll ever be.

Answer (score 0):

Once you assign a new value to a variable, the reference is lost. You could however use an object wrapper around your function:

```
var a = { func: function() { console.log(5); } };
var b = a;
b.func(); // will print 5 to the console

a.func = function() { console.log(6); };
b.func(); // will print 6 to the console
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't give you direct control over pointers, but you can work around that by never re-assigning `a` or `b`. Instead set them both to point to the same object, then change a property of the object, like this.

```
var a = {fn:function() {console.log(5);}};
var b = a;
a.fn = function() {console.log(6);};
b.fn(); // logs 6
```

Comment: That's not true.  All variables are pointers (or rather references).  However, you can't take the address of a variable or create a reference to a variable.

Comment: Sorry, my wording (or thinking...) was a little foggy. Hopefully it's clearer now.